# Get file object by giving hardcoded path in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, path

I need to get file from my disk (i.e. local machine) by giving a path in javascript. How to do that using javascript or jquery? I have get the file on single button click by giving hardcoded path. I don't want to browse file by using `<input type="file">`
Following is my code:

```
<button id="btnCallApi">Call Api</button>
```

```
<script>
 $('#btnCallApi').on('click', function (evt) {           
        var files= "file:///H:/abc/xyz/testTxtDoc.txt";
alert(files);
});
</script>
```

How to get that file object from specified location path?

Comment: This is not possible! How do you know about client PC file hierarchy?

Comment: in what environment? If you mean in a browser you need to use a web path and page needs to load from web server

Comment: I am executing this code to get file object from my local machine, not from client's machine

Comment: I am giving a hardcoded file path from my local machin disc and want to get that file

Comment: "my local machin" means your local server right? any way it should be a server

Comment: I want to get file simply from my drive (i.e. H:) of my computer on button click by JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
 url: "file:///H:/abc/xyz/testTxtDoc.txt"
}).done(function(data) {
 alert(data);
```

});

Comment: This code is giving me an error as
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///H:/abc/xyz/testTxtDoc.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: there you have your answer then: The file-path only works, if your original JS-File was loaded via the same kind of path. Alternatives I see: put your data on your webserver or store it in a cookie or load your entire website via `file://` or fiddle with the security-settings of your browser to allow this kind of requests.